How exactly do partitions work in Spark shuffling?
I am a bit curious about the internals of how a data shuffle happens over a cluster am currently trying to get a deeper understanding of what goes on in the internals of Spark Shuffle, particularly the default Sort Shuffle in Spark. My questions mainly lie with the notion of partitions and the index file generated during the shuffle.
My current understanding is that when a shuffle is needed in a Spark application, assuming the data is already partitioned across the cluster in some way, there is a map task executed for every partition of the data. Each map task will process their partition of data, and the data will be stored in memory using the Spark AppendOnlyMap structure, which is a hash table with the shuffle partition ID being the key in the hash table. Before generating the map ouput and index file for each shuffle partition, the mapped data is also sorted based on shuffle partition key.

Why exactly do we need to sort the mapped data according to the hashed shuffle partition key? I am having quite a bit of trouble wrapping my head around the reason this sort is needed (to me, it doesn't seem necessary but from what I read online, it is done quite often), so if anyone could help explain this that would be greatly appreciated

What does the shuffle index file do? I have a general understanding of it (I believe it tells each reducer where its respective block of data starts in the shuffle data) - is this understanding correct?

In the Spark Configurations page (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html), I see a parameter called spark.sql.shuffle.partitions, which says controls the number of partitions to use when shuffling data for joins or aggregations. Are the partitions here separate from the partitions the actual data is stored in and is there any connection between the two?

Is there any relationship between the number of shuffle partitions and the number of mappers/reducers, and how exactly are the number of mappers and reducers calculated in Sort Shuffle? I know that the number of reducers in Spark's old Hash Shuffle was simply equal to the number of partitions from this article (https://0x0fff.com/spark-architecture-shuffle/), but it is quite old and I am wondering if that is still the case for the Sort Shuffle.


I have looked online for answers to these questions, but I couldn't find any that answer my specific questions. If anyone could help me, preferably with some examples, that would be greatly appreciated.

This may be useful: https://books.japila.pl/apache-spark-internals/shuffle/
